# Is there any difference between keybd_event() and SendKeys.SendWait()?

Tags: c#, sendkeys

Is SendKeys.SendWait() just a wrapper and these two code snippets are identical?

```
const int VK_ESCAPE = 0x1B;
keybd_event(VK_ESCAPE, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_ESCAPE, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

and

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ESC}");
```

If not, is there any reason to use one over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

keybd_event() is a legacy API, you're supposed to use SendInput() these days.  SendKeys either uses a journaling hook or SendInput, depending on .config file setting.  The journaling hook is legacy and still the default, SendInput works better on Vista and up, available since .NET 3.  So, roughly, yes they are the same.  The config setting is:

```
<appSettings> 
    <add key="SendKeys" value="SendInput"/> 
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation.  I wish they'd make their mind up!

Answer (score 1):

The most recent versions of `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys` use [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx), although you have to [configure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait.aspx) it to do so. Hans has explained about the alternative journaling hook method of `SendKeys`.

`SendInput` is the officially sanctioned API call for faking input.  The documentation to `keybd_event` states:

> **Note**  This function has been
>   superseded. Use SendInput instead.

You should probably use `SendKeys` because its lots easier.